# Big Sur and Seagate 2TB Expansion Drive Slow

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, external-disk

I've been using these [2TB Seagate Expansion Drives](https://www.seagate.com/products/external-hard-drives/expansion-external-drives) for a while with Logic Pro, but today it the HD usage in Logic Pro keeps maxing out:

[image: Performance Meter Maxing Out]

The specific model of the one I just purchased is the [STGX2000400](https://www.cnet.com/products/seagate-portable-drive-stgx2000400-hard-drive-2-tb-usb-3-0/) with "Date First Available" of `July 3, 2018`.

```
Interface Speed, 5.0 Gbps (USB 3.0) / 480 Mbps (USB 2.0)
```

CPU usage is negligible.

I tried moving Logic's Sound Library to a different drive, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Disc Utility didn't find any errors on the drive and a Disc Speed Test returns the following:

[image: Disc Speed Test External]

Which compares very unfavorably to a test on the internal drive:

[image: Disc Speed Test Internal]

However another Seagate 2TB Expansion drive shows the same speed, so maybe that's expected.

Disc Util reports the following on the Seagate External drive:

```
diskutil info disk3s1
   Device Identifier:         disk3s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk3s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk3

   Volume Name:               Ochosi
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Ochosi

   Partition Type:            Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:   Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):             hfs
   Name (User Visible):       Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                   Journal size 155648 KB at offset 0x3a3b000
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               2C87162C-67CF-3514-B171-3AE12C60F168
   Partition Offset:          32768 Bytes (64 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 2.0 TB (2000396321280 Bytes) (exactly 3907024065 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        2.0 TB (2000396320768 Bytes) (exactly 3907024064 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:         738.5 GB (738459410432 Bytes) (exactly 1442303536 512-Byte-Units) (36.9%)
   Volume Free Space:         1.3 TB (1261935861760 Bytes) (exactly 2464718480 512-Byte-Units) (63.1%)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          No

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Info not available
```

The temperature in the room is about 85-90 degrees, so I'm wondering if that is causing the issue.

Comment: What model disk and when manufactured? Need ask to discover whether it uses shingled magnetic recording (SMR) and it probably does! I would expect about 100 MB/s for a consumer hard disk that doesn't use SMR. So 50 MB/s maybe about right for yours.

Comment: Looks like your internal drive is NVMe or similar - they're factors faster than any spinny rust is capable of. I tested a few drives around the building. Internal HDs over SATA I'm seeing about 150 each way, on USB2 only 30MB/s Seagate don't seem to give any spec on what drives are in those enclosures, but 60 might be about right for a 5200 rpm drive [based on a bit of guesswork] A 7200 or faster should do better. Until we know precisely what's in the box, that's best guess.

Comment: Added details including link to specific model and `Interface Speed, 5.0 Gbps (USB 3.0) / 480 Mbps (USB 2.0)`.

Comment: By heck, but they're cagey about it. The 'drive spec' gives only the interface speed [which is about as much use as a chocolate fireplace]. Those interface speeds are simply the generic speeds… for those interfaces, USB 2.1, USB 3.0. Absolutely no indication of what drive is in it or what **its** transfer speeds are. This is why people [who are aware of this marketing shi… ermm…  strategy] buy internal drives & drop into specific dock/caddy structures. That way you know what you bought.

Comment: It's not too late to return (and replace) it, which is now my intention. I am not sure if, for audio as well as application locations, SSD or HDD is better, nor whether Thunderbolt would be a better connection. I expect USB 3 should be sufficient. SMART appears to be a useful feature. Not sure if that applies both to SSD and HDD or not.

Comment: Not trying to sell you anything, but if you're serious about 'pro audio' you maybe need to be looking at RAID structures. Promise RAID were heavily into Mac audio/video on the 'trash can' Mac Pros, when you could no longer fill them full of drives. These days, you could probably be looking towards SSD equivalents, though they might be pricey. As an audio engineer still with a building full of old 'cheesegrater' Mac Pros, I still have the luxury of putting a couple of SSDs & 4 HDs in each machine, so it's not an architecture I've yet had to fully investigate.

Comment: Oh, for sure if you can get modern Thunderbolt 3 equivalents of any of this type of structure, seriously investigate it. Personally, it's a bit 'too new' for these Macs, so it not an area i have any expertise in.

Comment: We are definitely serious about `Pro Audio`. It does appear that SSD drives can be RAID configured. https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/ssd-raid-008.html We actually have a QNAP system, but I haven't tried recording to and from it in Logic. It's connected via Cat5 ethernet cable.

Comment: QNAP is something I'm aware of but never used, so I can't really give any advice on it, sorry… except that if it's Cat5, it's going to be at best 1000BaseT, so your speed limit is going to be that… 100MB/s [slower than an SATA hard drive even under absolutely ideal conditions], no matter what the QNAP is capable of